# How to mock an XMLHTTP interface using SoapUI?

Tags: soapui

I am creating a mock for various http calls using SoapUI.

Most of these are proper SOAP calls, for which I have WSDL files, but some are just ugly XML-over-HTTP with no proper service definition, and I dont know how to handle those (the real underlying system is zOS/CICS, in case you are interested)

I have samples of the requests from log files, but I dont have admin rights so I cannot (at least not easily) record the actual communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, using the following OnRequest script for the MockService, and a bogus mockoperation (otherwise the OnRequest script will not trigger):

```
mockRunner.returnFile(mockRequest.httpResponse, new File("response.xml"))
return new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockResult(mockRequest)
```

Also see:
http://www.soapui.org/Service-Mocking/mocking-rest-services.html